# A Curve is Geodesic iff it is Extremal to Energy Functional

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

In my lecture notes, geodesic is defined to be a curve that is parametrized proportional to arc length and an extremal to the length functional:
$$l(\alpha)=\int_a^b |\alpha'(t)|dt \quad (1)$$
In the section Riemannian geometry in the Wikipedia page [Geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic), it said that geodesic can also be defined as an extremal to the energy functional:
$$E(\alpha)=\frac{1}{2}\int_a^b |\alpha'(t)|^2dt\quad (2)$$
Due to the fact that $(l(\alpha))^2 \leq (b-a)E(\alpha)$ with equality iff $\alpha$ is parametrized proportional to arc length, it is easy to show that if $\alpha$ is a geodesic as defined in $(1)$, then it is a geodesic as defined in $(2).$

But how can I show that if $\alpha$ is an extremal to the energy functional, then it is parametrized by arc length? Or is it a condition that is required for these two definitions to be equivalent?

Comment: Hi there, I am pretty sure you are missing a factor of 2 on the RHS of the inequality. :) Btw, are you able to rigorously prove the equality, if so I'd be interested in seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

If $\gamma$ is an extremum of the energy functional $E$, then $\gamma$ is parameterized proportional to arc length.

Unfortunately, I don't see a "tricky" proof of this fact, and so I'm afraid that the explanation I'm going to try to give may use too much machinery (given that you are learning the definition of a geodesic). At minimum you will need to be familiar with the idea of a covariant derivative along a curve (see do Carmo, section 2.2, proposition 2.2).

To (hopefully) review, given a curve $\gamma$ in a Riemannian manifold, there's a well-defined way to take the "derivative" of a vector field $V$ defined along $\gamma$ (i.e., for each $t$ in the domain of $\gamma$ we have a vector $V(t) \in T_{\gamma(t)} M$, and these vectors should vary smoothly in $t$). This derivative we denote by $D_t V$ or $\nabla_{\gamma'(t)} V$ depending on whether $\gamma$ is clear from context.

In order to prove that extrema of the energy functional are parameterized proportional to arc length, the standard thing to do is to just use the first variation formula, a fundamental result in Riemannian Geometry. I'll outline the setup and result; this is done more carefully in **do Carmo, section 9.2**.

Let $\Gamma: (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \times (a, b) \to M$ be a smooth map. We write $\gamma_s(t)$ for $\Gamma(s,t)$, and we think of $\Gamma$ as a "variation" of paths around $\gamma_0$. We make the further restriction that $\Gamma$ fixes the endpoints of $\gamma$; that is, $\gamma_s(a) = \gamma(a)$ and $\gamma_s(b) = \gamma(b)$ for all $s$.

The statement that $\gamma$ is an extremum for the energy functional is exactly the statement that for all such variations $\gamma_s$ with $\gamma_0 = \gamma$, we have $\left. \frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=0} E(\gamma_s) = 0$. It's therefore tempting (and useful) to explicitly compute the derivative $\left. \frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=0} E(\gamma_s)$, for arbitary curves $\gamma$ and arbitrary variations $\gamma_s$. We obtain the following:

**First variation formula, simple form.** If $\Gamma$ is a smooth variation fixing the endpoints of $\gamma$, then
$$
  \left. \frac{d}{ds} \right|_{s=0} E(\gamma_s) = -2 \int_a^b \langle \partial_s \Gamma, D_t \gamma_s' \rangle dt.
$$
Here $D_t \gamma'_s$ is the covariant derivative of $\gamma'_s$ along the curve $t \mapsto \gamma_s(t)$ (which might sometimes be written $\nabla_{\gamma'_s} \gamma'_s$).

Proving this isn't particularly difficult once the machinery is familiar. The point now is that since $\Gamma$ is (relatively) arbitrary, it follows that **any extremum $\gamma$ of the energy functional must satisfy $D_t \gamma'(t) = 0$.**

I'll remark that the equation $D_t \gamma'(t) = 0$ is often called the *geodesic equation*, and geodesics are often defined to be those curves that satisfy the geodesic equation. (One must then use an argument like this one to show that such curves minimize the length functional.)

Finally, it follows from $D_t \gamma'(t) = 0$ that $||\gamma'(t)||$ is constant in $t$, since
$$
  \frac{d}{dt} ||\gamma'(t)||^2 = 2 \langle D_t \gamma'(t), \gamma'(t) \rangle = 0,
$$
and of course it follows from this that $\gamma$ is parameterized proportional to arc length, since the arc length of $\gamma$ from $t_1$ to $t_2$ is just
$$
 \int_{t_1}^{t_2} || \gamma'(t) || dt.
$$

Comment: Hey, there. I dont see the very last conclusion, why does constant norm of the tangent vector imply that the curve is affinely parametrized? What do you get from the very last formula?

Comment: If $||\gamma'(t)|| = c$ for all $t$, then the last formula tells you that the arc length $s(t_1, t_2)$ of $\gamma$ between $\gamma(t_1)$ and $\gamma(t_2)$ is just $c(t_2 - t_1)$. (I am not sure I understand what's confusing; perhaps I am making some dumb mistake. This may look more familiar if you set $a = 0$ and note that it then implies that the arc length of $\gamma$ from $\gamma(0)$ to $\gamma(t)$ is just $s = ct$, i.e., $t = s/c$.)

Comment: Hm, I see all of this but I dont see what it has to with the parametrization of $\gamma$ . What is the definition of being parametrized proportional to arc-length?

Comment: If $\gamma: [a, b] \to M$ is a curve and we denote by $s(t_1, t_2)$ the arc length of $\gamma$ between $t_1$ and $t_2$, then saying that $\gamma$ is "parameterized proportional to arc length" should mean that there exists $\alpha > 0$ such that for any $t_1, t_2 \in [a, b]$ with $t_2 > t_1$ we have $s(t_1, t_2) = \alpha(t_2 - t_1)$. (That is, the change in the parameter for $\gamma$ (the $t$) is proportional to the arc length of the corresponding segment of $\gamma$.)